# Running tests with VS Code (without Maven) using the "Test Runner for Java" extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, junit5

I'm trying to make a minimal working example of JUnit5 using Visual Studio code without Maven. The reason is that I'm trying to make a quick demo for 1st year students, and I don't have the time to explain Maven (it will be the subject of a later course).

My VS Code workspace has this structure (I'm on Linux so forward slashes are normal) :

[image: very basic project structure]

The settings.json file contains:

```
{
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
    "demojunit/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.8.1.jar"
    ]
}
```

The DemoJUnit.java contains:

```
package demojunit;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DemoJUnit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int integer = -1;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 20 : ");
            if (keyboard.hasNextInt())
            integer = keyboard.nextInt();
                keyboard.nextLine();
        } while ((integer < 1) || (integer > 20));

        keyboard.close();

        long result = computeFactorial(integer);
        System.out.println("The factorial " + integer + "! gives " + result);
    }

    public static long computeFactorial(int number) {
        if (number < 1)
            return -1;
        if (number > 20)
            return -2;

        long factorial = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            factorial = factorial * i;
        }

        return factorial;
    }
}
```

And the DemoJUnitTest.java contains:

```
package demojunit;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class DemoJUnitTest {
    @Test
    public static void computeFactorial_CleanTest() {
        long expected_value = 120;
        long real_value = DemoJUnit.computeFactorial(5);
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected_value, real_value);
    }

    @Test public static void computeFactorial_DirtyTest() {
        long expected_value = -1;
        long real_value = DemoJUnit.computeFactorial(0);
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected_value, real_value);
    }
}
```

The settings.json seems to work since the imports and @Test are not marked as errors in VS Code.

As you can see in the folder image, I downloaded the latest JUnit5 jar file, and it works when running from the command line:

[image: output from running junit from the console]

However, running from the command line is not convenient, so I installed the "Test Runner for Java" extension.

The problem is that when running tests, something fails and I don't have any error messages, nor any indication what went wrong. I changed the extensions' settings to be `verbose` but I still get no error messages in the Terminal, the Debug Console, nor anywhere else.

All I get is :

[image: extension shows 0/0 tests failed]

Any idea why the extension fails (and fails to give any indication on why it fails)?

Comment: It looks like your tests are declared static and therefore not picked up as tests.  Notice your console test run doesn't actually run any tests.  It finds test containers, but no actual tests.  Notice also that your Test Runner screen shots also don't indicate those static methods are recognized as actual tests.